# AWS - ELB error page redirection to a different domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-elb

How do I configure ELB to redirect all error traffic to a website say `www.myhome.com` instead of it printing `CANNOT GET /efsdf'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This is a load balancer - it "balances" traffic by redirecting it to instances. You'll have to handle the request when it arrives to your instance (at the web-server/application level).

Comment: AHProxy is a load balancer (a good one) and has support for this ;)